# How do I retrieve the controls created by a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list of objects that I need to represent as a list of buttons.
These buttons should normally act as a regular Button; when the checkbox is checked, they should work as ToggleButtons and remain pressed. But I also need them to be mutually exclusive, like a RadioButton (only one can only be toggled at any time).

I tried using a RadioButton as the template for my ItemsControl, but they are not mutually exclusive (I guess that they are not actually children of the same control).

So I thought to use a ToggleButton as the template, manually uncheck it if the checkbox is not checked, and manually handle the mutual exclusion.
However, I can't find a way to retrieve the toggle buttons for the other items in the list to uncheck them.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp9.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<UniformGrid Rows="1">
    <UniformGrid.Resources>          
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
            <ToggleButton Name="Toggle"                              
                          Checked="ToggleButton_Checked"
                          Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UniformGrid.Resources>

    <ItemsControl Name="lst" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}" />

    <CheckBox Name="CheckToggle"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
        TOGGLE
    </CheckBox>
</UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

And this is my code-behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace WpfApp9
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lst.ItemsSource = new[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
        }

        private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var toggle = (ToggleButton)sender;

            // If the checkbox is not checked, release the button immediately
            if (CheckToggle.IsChecked != true)
                toggle.IsChecked = false;

            // now how do I uncheck the other ToggleButtons?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem above in a different way.
In the question I said that

> I tried using a RadioButton as the template for my ItemsControl, but they are not mutually exclusive (I guess that they are not actually children of the same control)

but I didn't realize I could use the `GroupName` property to force them into the same group. At this point the template can be this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
        <RadioButton Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
                     GroupName="SomeGroupName"
                     Content="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And I get my mutually exclusive buttons without handling them manually.